# Getting "replacement transaction underpriced" though not trying to replace a transaction

Tags: web3js, transactions, rinkeby, infura

I'm running an airdrop script which essentially loops a database of recipients and invokes a `batchTransfer` function each time with 80 different recipients and amounts.
After about 10 successful submissions, each new submission is rejected with "replacement transaction underpriced" - though the data of the request is different!
The stack is `web3`|`infura`|`rinkeby`

I read the [answer here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27256/error-replacement-transaction-underpriced) but not sure it applies. Will changing the nonce solve it? Where do I do it anyway? is nonce a param I add to the json array along with `gas` and `gasPrice`? And anyway, why doesn't the network see the data is different in each transaction I try to submit?

Comment: I've had the same issue. It is Infura being a load balancer for a lot of nodes is causing this. Unfortunately, I could not find a way around it and ran them sequentially (all 2000tx I had to make)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can indeed change the `nonce` by hand; it is a transaction parameter and it goes alongside `gas`, `gasPrice`, `value`.

So your script can simply increment it then fire and forget the transaction.

Now, you need to find out the nonce value of the first transaction you fire. Easy: `var firstNonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(yourSender);`.

Edit:

Infura servers are at different states, so if your script calls `web3.eth.getTransactionCount` behind the scenes, it will get different results. Your script needs to keep track of the incrementing nonce and only call `getTransactionCount` once.

Comment: I now realise the nonce *is* the way to overwrite existing transactions and the data is not checked at all? Why do I get transactions submitted with an existing nonce in the first place? Ah, is this what the infura load balancing problem about? They invoke the getTransacrionCount each time on a different node and get a different response each time?

Comment: Yes, correct, Infura's servers have different states. That's why your script must keep track of the latest nonce sent and call `getTransactionCount` only once.

Comment: Now that I've added `nonce` to the json I send along with the contract invocation, I get a tx hash, but when I look it up on etherscan it's not found. I tried on rinkeby, ropsten and kovan, so I believe its systematic. What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: started it as a new question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52581/how-to-properly-set-nonce-in-a-web3-contract-invocation I really want to mark this one as correct but must see I can control the nonce...

Answer (score 0):

set the following gas limit and gas price:-
                 //gas limit

`public  static final BigInteger GAS_LIMIT = 
      BigInteger.valueOf(4_300_000);`

```
             //gas price
```

`public  static final BigInteger GAS_PRICE = 
       BigInteger.valueOf(22_000_000_000L);`