# How to properly set nonce in a web3 contract invocation?

Tags: web3js, infura, nonce

I have this code, which works:

```
MyToken.airdrop(wallets,amounts,{
  gas: 1267051,
  gasPrice: 2000000000,
},function(err,tx){
  console.log('err is %s',err)
  console.log('tx is %s',tx)
  callback(err,tx)
})
```

Now Let's say I want to control the `nonce` myself ([reason here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52496/getting-replacement-transaction-underpriced-though-not-trying-to-replace-a-tra)) so I do:

```
MyToken.airdrop(wallets,amounts,{
  gas: 1267051,
  gasPrice: 2000000000,
  nonce: 432 // = web3.eth.getTransactionCount() + 1
},function(err,tx){
  console.log('err is %s',err)
  console.log('tx is %s',tx)
  callback(err,tx)
})
```

I get a tx hash as output, *not an error*, yet the transaction can't be found on the appropriate etherscan, it seems to never get sent to the network. Tried on Rinkeby, Ropsten, and Kovan.

What could be the problem with specifying `nonce` myself or the way I'm doing it?

Note: I'm using `infura` as the "node".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently there's a nuance with the nonce... my error was I was setting the nonce to web3.eth.getTransactionCount() + 1, which left a gap between prior transaction nonce and next transaction nonce (**nonces are 0 indexed, transactions are indexed from 1**, that's the root of the error). It so appears that you are not allowed to increment the nonce by 2 and leave a gap. Must be sequential.

Comment: You are *allowed* to send a tx with a nonce too high, but it will not be mined before the gap is filled. And you have to trust the miners to keep the high-nonce-tx in their tx pool while you fill the gap.

Comment: Good catch! didn't know of the discrepancy in indexing.

Comment: would be great to see the working code in your answer.