# Error from sendSignedTransaction: Error: Returned error: replacement transaction underpriced

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, mist, contract-deployment

I am the beginner in Ethereum stuff need guidance please help
I am running a private ethereum network and using mist wallet 
here is my contract code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract MyFirstContract {
    uint256 counter =0;

    function increase() public {
        counter++;
    }

    function  decrease() public{
        counter--;
    }

    function getCounter() public constant  returns (uint256) {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

the counter value was not changing when I press  execute `increment` or `decrement` function counter value was not changing after many tries i got these error message
I am getting the error message "`Error from sendSignedTransaction: Error: Returned error: replacement transaction underpriced`"after some researching I found out this answer
[error: replacement transaction underpriced](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27256/error-replacement-transaction-underpriced)
I have one pending transaction

web3.eth.pendingTransactions();

```
[{
    blockHash: null,
    blockNumber: null,
    from: "0x4f7f384236f79a5e3322e33cc7bb2ccd5143a87c",
    gas: 188189,
    gasPrice: 18000000000,
    hash: "0x193d30297d98ad9da5958e6295d61bf333050cec901601ccdbf83e9c0b1cb082",
    input: "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",
    nonce: 10,
    r: "0x34fa67311a0a29d31139a425c2ab120033d4ab34a6d1a860d6c806f95412f7af",
    s: "0x7d831f773e541f73a2371be911ec29b36d803db414ab4712007c4b00d4f10be9",
    to: null,
    transactionIndex: 0,
    v: "0x1b",
    value: 0
}]
```

so I increased the nounce 
        web3.eth.getTransactionCount("0x4f7f384236f79a5e3322e33cc7bb2ccd5143a87c")+1;
    11

after then I again try to exceute the transaction but again getting these messages 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Nonces are 0 indexed, transactions are indexed from 1**. [This](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52581/how-to-properly-set-nonce-in-a-web3-contract-invocation) post here mentions:

> Apparently there's a nuance with the nonce... my error was I was
>   setting the nonce to web3.eth.getTransactionCount() + 1, which left a
>   gap between prior transaction nonce and next transaction nonce (nonces
>   are 0 indexed, transactions are indexed from 1, that's the root of the
>   error). It so appears that you are not allowed to increment the nonce
>   by 2 and leave a gap. Must be sequential.

**Requested instructions:**
You need to find out the nonce value of the first transaction you fire.

```
var firstNonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(yourSender);.
```

The post I linked above and [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52581/how-to-properly-set-nonce-in-a-web3-contract-invocation) shows how to set nonce manually(and a common error, that `getTransactionCount` already returns a value one higher than the nonce and was the reason for my answer)

Comment: can you please elaborate what i have to do as an example as i am a beginner i am having a dificulty  in understanding this

Comment: @swaheed I've edited it to include more detail. Also, if you are using infura, make sure you call getTransactionCount only once and you are manually keeping track of the increasing nonce.