# Transaction underpriced on Metamask?

Tags: etherscan, erc-721, gas-price, burn

I'm trying to burn one of my ERC721 tokens in my deployed contract but as you can see from my image the transaction fails with that error even if I did not touch anything when metamask prompts me to sign the transaction. How can I solve this?
[image: image of transaction sign]
[image: image of my etherscan]

Comment: See this thread: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27256/error-replacement-transaction-underpriced

Comment: Hi @Kerry99 thank you for your reply. The issue solved itself, this morning when I started to work it was magically working again. Thank you again :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the RPC url in Metamask worked instantly for me.