# Optimizing ETH transaction code

Tags: web3js, transactions, javascript

I am using the below code for executing ETH transactions with web3.js

Is it an optimized code? is there any room for improvements, what else can I add, or how can I handle exceptions/errors

```
const transactEthereum = async (privKey, addressFrom, addressTo, amount) => {

   // Configuring the connection to an Ethereum node
    const network = process.env.ETHEREUM_NETWORK;
    const web3 = new Web3(
        new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
        `https://${network}.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_PROJECT_ID}`
        )
    );

    const tx = {

        from: addressFrom,
        to: addressTo,
        value: amount

    }

    // Assigning the right amount of gas
    tx.gas = await web3.eth.estimateGas(tx);

    // nonce starts counting from 0
    tx.nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addressFrom, 'latest');

   const createTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
      tx,
      privKey
   );

   // Deploy transaction
   const createReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
      createTransaction.rawTransaction
   );

   console.log(
      `Transaction successful with hash: ${createReceipt.transactionHash}`
   );

   return createReceipt.transactionHash;

};
```

Comment: The code is perfectly fine. It will work well in the majority of the situations. There are a few thing that you may want to improve: the web3 provider is down, there's a pending transaction, the network is congested and the gas price is too high, there isn't enough ether to pay the transaction fees, the target is a contract that reverts. If none of those cases applies to your use case then the code will work correctly.

Comment: @Ismael how can I do those things code wise, I am new to web3.js

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem for most cases. If the transaction takes too long to confirm then you could diagnose, and allow the user to send a replacement transaction. See this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/44875/ for an explanation how to do it.